# Saving raw json as a nested property to raven DB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

The json structure i need to save as a nested property (which is a list of child docs) is constantly changing and i dont want to maintain the class structure.

So i want a class something like

```
 public class Doc
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DocName { get; set; }
        public List<String> NestedProperty { get; set; }

    }
```

I want raven DB to understand the json and include it in the saved doc as json, not escape it as a string.

Is there a way i can do this with RavenJArray or RavenJObject or something else?

this works

```
public class Doc
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DocName { get; set; }
        public List<dynamic> NestedProperty { get; set; }

    }
```

thanks @Wyatt Barnett

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do anything on the raven side -- such as indexing the NestedProperty -- then string that you deserialize on the client is not a bad option really. Raven will escape it because it stores stuff in json so it needs to escape it but it will come out as a nice json string when you request it.

If I was keeping these child docs in raven I would probably look to keep a list of the IDs in my doc and then use a result transformer to pull out the docs as a dynamic. I'm guessing you know what types these things should be so you can transform further from there.

I also had some success on one project storing polymorphic lists as projected child objects but that got loopy in some places and I'm not sure if that trick would work on current versions of ravendb.

If you really want raven to see it a bit more you could store it as dynamic but you'll still have some challenges getting it out -- it will come out just fine but how are you going to know what properties the dynamic object has unless you are tracking that somehow and then that isn't so dynamic is it?

Comment: So raven cant add create the document structure from the string?
will it always be stored as
{
  "Name": "some name",
  "PageName": "some other name",
  "Messages": [
    "{\r\n  \"post_id\":\"1"
  ]
}

is there no way to get raven to understand the structure without the class mapping?

Comment: I tweaked the answer a bit -- dynamic should save it as an object in raven but I'm really not sure if that gets you more than storing it as a string and deserializing in the client app.

Comment: This doesnt work when the trying to get the json back out. So when deserialising back to the List<Dynamic> i get a "Could not convert document Page/2 to entity of type FbPage.Page" error any ideas?

Comment: If you know what type it is why are you trying to use dynamic? You should probably post a bit more code, especially how things are going and and out of the database. My general sense is there is probably a better approach to take to what you are doing but it is hard to tell where you are going based on the evidence so far.